# How to redirect STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR to a file in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have seen a number of examples where you can redirect the STD in/out/err of a single command to a file. So I was able to create a myLogger.bat as a wrapper that redirects the call statement of myScript to myLogFile.

Sample code of myLogger:

```
CALL "%xDir%\%%1" > "%lDir%\%lFil%" 2>&1
```

From the command line I execute> `myLogger.bat myScriptToBeLogged.bat`

However I was not able to redirect STD in/out/err of all the commands in a windows batch file(.bat)

Is there anything similar to "exec > $logFile 2>&1 in shell" that could be included in the beginning of the batch script which will redirect all the logs of the same script to a file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really; the scripts are windows batch files (.bat)

Comment: Why do they have to be batch?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, you will want to do this with `1> (STDOUT)` and `2> (STDERR)`

So, for example:

```
dir 1>stout.txt 2>stderr.txt
```

For more details, and how to do clever things with STDIN, see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: Here you are redirecting the STD out/err independently to two files. But again you are doing it for only one command of the batch file in this case `dir`.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it. Simply CALL a routine at the beginning with redirection.

```
@echo off
>test.log 2>&1 call :start %*
exit /b

:start
REM rest of script goes here.
```